# Webscraping in R From Dataframe

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

From the following data frame

[image]

I am trying to use the package rvest to scrape each words Part of speech and synonyms from the website: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/research?s=t into a csv.

I am not sure how to have R search each word of the data frame and pull its Part of Speech and Synonym.

`install.packages("rvest")
    install.packages("xml2")
    library(xml2)
    library(rvest)
    library(dplyr)
 words<data.frame("keywords"=c("research","survey","staff","outpatient","consent")) 
html<- read_html("https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/research")
html %>%  html_nodes(".mw-list") %>% html_text () %>% 
head(n=1) # take the first 1st records`

Comment: What have you tried? There's several rvest tutorials out there to get you started...

Comment: If you intend one query per keyword, I'd expect `lapply` (or `purrr::map`) to be a useful addition to `rvest`.

Comment: I am very new to web scraping and not sure how to have r loop through a data frame in a web search and give me the results of the first record for each word without doing so manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search [your term] on thesaurus, you will end up on the following HTML page: "https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/[your term]". If you know this, you can get the HTMLs of all the pages of terms you're interested in. After that you should be able to iterate with the `map()` function from the `purrr` pacakage to get the information you want:

```
# It makes more sense to just keep "words" as a vector for now

words <- c("research","survey","staff","outpatient","consent")
htmls <- paste0("https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/", words)

info_list <- map(htmls, .x %>%
                          read_html() %>%
                          html_node(.mw-list) %>%
                          html_text())
```

Comment: Thank you  so much for your help Adam! I really appreciate it. For some reason when i run map function i get the following error                                                                     
`Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object '.x' not found  `                                                  I am not sure why this might be happening

Comment: I'm sorry, I was running some models while I was writing the reply so I didn't actually run the code & made some mistakes (forgot tilde "~" and quotation marks around html node). 

Anyway, I fixed the code, tried running it, and the HTML node that you used in your original post (".mw-list") didn't work for me. I'm not sure if that's exactly what your want, but I did get it to work with the following node:

`info_list <- map(htmls, ~ .x %>%
      read_html() %>%
      html_node('.e9i53te0') %>%
      html_text())`

Comment: No worries! I Btw if you ever can't find the right HTML node, you can use [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/). Also there's some great `rvest` tutorials out there, e.g. https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-web-scraping-rvest, so check out those if you ever get stuck.